# Limit video buffer to X seconds in YouTube iframe player

Tags: ios, iframe, uiwebview, youtube, youtube-api

I have a YouTube IFrame player in a UIWebView. When the video is paused, the player keeps caching the video until its end. I'd like to limit the buffered part to no more than X seconds after the pausing/playing time point. How can I do that?

I haven't found any caching control in the [IFrame API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference).

In the official iOS YouTube app, the caching seems to be limited to around 30s after the pausing/playing time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no control over buffering through iFrame API. Buffering is usually determined with respect to viewer's own platform, device and connection and dynamically adjusted on the fly rather being controlled statically.

If that's the case for YouTube app or for the best of the user, that should be coming to the embed as well. You don't need to worry or try to control it.

Comment: Thanks @Ibrahim. I am asking this question because such caching can be used for offline playing of the video, which is not in compliance with the YouTube terms. I thought there might be an elegant way to solve this.